# Where can I find reliable entertainment reviews which are targeted for parents?

Tags: games, movies

Is there a reliable, online, place, where I can find reviews for video games, board games, toys and movies which are aimed at parents, especially parents with young children?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have recommended [Common Sense Media](http://www.commonsensemedia.org) in response to a [similar question about movies](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/posts/73/edit), and it turns out that they provide similarly high quality reviews for the following media:

- Movies
- Games
- Apps
- Websites
- TV
- Books
- Music

They have rankings for age appropriateness, as well for rankings and explanations for specific categories that parents are likely to find relevant. You can search by media type, by age, and more.

Comment: "Common Sense" ratings are available right in Netflix, which is a great feature. They're very thoughtful and detailed.

Answer (score 3):

The BBFC (British Board of Film Classification) has an extremely good reputation for rating movies, and then explaining WHY a movie is so rated.

They're the ones responsible for the legal rating of British films, and their ratings are like this.

- U(c): Universally Acceptable but aimed for a very young audience.
- U: Universally Acceptable
- PG: Acceptable, but requires parental
  approval for young children
- 12A: 12 year olds allowed in
  unaccompanied, or anyone accompanied
  by an adult. (not recommended for
  anyone below 8)
- 15: No-one under 15
- 18: No-one under 18

Their parent-centred website is here: http://www.pbbfc.co.uk/ and they also do an app for mobile.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered a lot of new board games and other various content through GeekDad(http://www.wired.com/geekdad/).  It's much more of an active blog than a searchable site with reviews and it contains a lot of content other than what you're asking about, but it's well made and highlights a lot of great things I probably wouldn't have otherwise found.

Answer (score 1):

I use general review sites for judging if the game is appropriate for my son or not.

Every popular review site I know (metacritic, imdb, boardgamegeek, amazon, etc.) contains information about genre, PG rating, basic description, screenshots (or photos) and so on. This general information normally gives me enough data to decide if the game is appropriate. Moreover, boargamegeek and amazon contain info about appropriate age, which also gives me an idea if the toy or game is too complicated.

If I doubt, I just describe, say, general game plot, show some screenshots or photos and see if it excites my son.